# a valid signing identity not be found?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am trying to create a distribution build with mono for days already... I got the distribution provisioning profile and the distribution certificate from our "team agent" and drag-dropped seperately onto xcode-organizer and keychain-access, but still, there's the warning message showing :

"A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain."

and I couldn't make the distribution build still. Any idea which step I made it wrong? Please advice; much appreciated!

Thanks,
ab.yyang

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you only have the provision file and the certificate from Apple, but not the original private key used to request the certificate.

If that's the case, you either have to ask whoever created it for a copy of private key, or you'll need to generate entirely new keys, request a new certificate and create a new provision file.

Answer (score 1):

1. open Keychain Access
2. erase everything in 'Keys' and 'Certificates'
3. open Xcode and erase all provisioning data
4. goto Provisioning Portal and revoke your certificate
5. create a new one, and use launch assistant

Comment: This won't work for him. He mentioned he's not the "team agent".

Answer (score 1):

If this happen after renewing the DEVELOPER CERTIFICATE,

my fix to the problem was going to the apple provision profile, modify the development provision and checkbox the certificate.(suppose to be empty checkbox near the certificate name).

then, you can : download and install the provision manually by dragging to xcode
or going to Organizer-Library(on the left)-Provision Profiles, and click the "refresh" button(in the bottom of screen), this will download the new provision profile that "connected" to the new CERTIFICATE and the warning will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building to run on a physical device, you need to be enrolled in the iOS Developer Program. From there you go to the Developer Portal to generate a Provisioning Profile. That profile gets loaded to Xcode via the Organizer window.

Have you done those steps?

Comment: Yes, I had provisioning profile loaded in xcode organizer, and the certificate loaded in keychain already. But I see the warning in xcode complaining that message, and couldn't make a build with that provisioning profile... (both are distribution version...)