# push notification certificate signing error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have to add push notifications to my app, I used this tutorial to implement it http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12
and http://lessons.runrev.com/m/4069/l/53405

after i followed all the mentioned instruction in the tutorial then install the new provisioning profile it gives me the following message next to provisioning profile

**valid signing identity not found**

I am sure the the public and privet keys in my keychain so what is this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

-->Connect to the apple developer member center then the iOS provisional portal.

-->Revoke my certificate.

-->Create a new certificate by providing a new pair of private and public key.

-->Remove all the previous provisioning profiles and create new ones.

-->Download the new provisioning profiles and install them in XCode by just dragging them to the XCode icon in the dock.

Hope it will help.

you can see the same  mentioned on these below sites

[xcode-4-valid-signing-identity-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769345/xcode-4-valid-signing-identity-not-found-error-on-provisioning-profiles-on-a)

[getting-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714517/getting-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be-found-in-yo)

[a-valid-signing-identity-not-be-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037031/a-valid-signing-identity-not-be-found)

Thanks