# Provisioning Profile 'Valid signing identity not found' error

Tags: xcode, keychain, provisioning-profile

I have an app that is ready for testing on my iPad, and I've created a development provisioning profile, matched up the bundleID and lowered the iOS deployment target.
However when I downloaded the profile and dragged it into the organizer, it says 'Valid signing identity not found'. I'm pretty sure this has got to do with the certificates in the keychain and private keys (???) however I have no idea how to fix this problem.

Can someone please point me to a tutorial or give me some advice on adding certificates into the keychain without using Xcode; stuff like the 'use for development' button isn't working for me!

Note:
The only valid Provisioning Profiles are distribution.
When I try to click 'Renew' Xcode says 'No value was provided for the parameter 'CertificateIDs'. I hope this helps!

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037031/a-valid-signing-identity-not-be-found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .p12 file associated with your provisioning profile is not found in your system keychain.

Check the below few things!

- Make sure you have enabled the correct certificate while generating the provisioning profile in the apple developer site.
- Check if you have any duplicates of the your certificate & private key more than once in your keychain access.
- If you do not have the .p12 corresponding to the provisioning profile, Get it exported from the mac system on which it was created & install it in your mac system.

Comment: When I tried that, it comes up in my organizer with 'valid code signing identity not found :-(

Comment: What did you try? Give the steps that you tried to resolve, may be that I help us proceed further!

Answer (score 1):

Check your code signing identity set your profile there.
and your Provisioning profile bundle id is same as your app bundle identifier.

Answer (score 1):

To do a valid code-signing - without using XCode - you need a valid certificate and key, corresponding to the provisioning profile :

- check with Keychain Access that you indeed have a 'iPhone distribution' certificate, with its own private key.
- Make sure this is the same certificate that was used on 'provisioning portal' to create you developement / distribution profile. If not, create a new one, or import the certificate from the other Mac you used when you created the provisioning
- Download the provisioning profile, and just double-click it.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this here because none of the other answers really went into enough detail to help me and I still had to figure it out on my own.

On the apple developer website, log in and under certificates click 'All'. The certificate needs to be generated on YOUR machine and with YOUR account or things do not build. This is what confused me... You can click the + icon and make a new certificate (development, or distribution). If it does not let you select for example Distribution, it's because there are already too many certificates in the account. So first, you have to delete an older certificate.

1) Delete the oldest certificate in the portal
2) Click the + and create a new certificate -- this will guide you through opening Keychain Access on your machine and requesting a certificate from apple, and you will have to save a file and upload it to the developer portal to create the certificate.
3) Download the new certificate and it will add to Keychain access
4) Go back to provisioning profiles on dev portal, click EDIT on the one you are trying to use and change it to use the newly generated certificate.
5) Download and click the provisioning profile
6) Everything works great.

This process actually was not that difficult, but for some reason I could not find the correct explanation anywhere. I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I did have all the private keys and everything was correct, but xcode refused to build and kept saying that I didn't have a valid provisioning profile and organiser showed 'valid signing identity not found'.

The solution involved:

- revoking my developer certificate and development provisioning profiles from the ios provisioning portal
- deleting those certificates from keychain
- try building again and tell xcode to 'fix issue'

This lets XCode manage the certificates, and it magically worked.

However on another project I still had the problem, and it was solved by this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966088/1192732